# Get spinner value when button click

Tags: android

Is it possible to return a spinner selected value only when I click in a button in the same activity, instead of using the OnItemSelected() method?

Answer (score 9):

Yes. You have several options to get the value. 
Some of these are:

```
spinner.getSelectedItem()
spinner.getSelectedItemId()
spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()
```

Just take a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) to see all the different methods you can call on your spinner.

Answer (score 1):

Yup. You can use 
`int position = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();`
to get position and then look for that item into your adapter's items list against this position. You will get the selected item info...